# html 5 form custom validation messages

Tags: html

there is a way to override the default messages on html 5 form validation.
so far it's seems the only way is

```
oninvalid="setCustomValidity('some message')"
```

it's possible to do that via CSS for example for all input text with a specific pattern or all input number?

thanks